# Question to do with ranking a data set based on 2 values in bigquery

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, distinct, rank

[image: Image_of_data]

Hi all! new to stackoverflow. I have a problem with RANK()OVER (PARTITION BY... in BigQuery.

The below table has 3 columns. Timestamp, Codes and User_id. I want to be able to rank these so for each Code, when there is a NEW user_id, it should count it as a new value.

```
rank    timestamp                      Codes            user_id
1       2020-08-21 17:13:37.457 UTC    XF7RNCNT4HF7XT   JR3k3LODRHHG
2       2020-08-24 01:39:21.625 UTC    XF7RNCNT4HF7XT   26a02014-20ae-43b6-b491-bd7292a143c4
2       2020-08-24 01:39:56.815 UTC    XF7RNCNT4HF7XT   26a02014-20ae-43b6-b491-bd7292a143c4
3       2020-08-26 21:30:47.215 UTC    XF7RNCNT4HF7XT   PC1795338
4       2020-08-29 18:54:48.032 UTC    XF7RNCNT4HF7XT   PC9602007
```

Comment: What happens if the user id changes back to a previous vlue on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to count each user only once for each code, on its first appearance date. Here is one approach using window functions:

```
select t.*, countif(rn = 1) over(partition by code order by timestamp) rnk
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by code, user_id order by timestamp) rn
    from mytable t
) t
```

The logic is to enumerate the rows of each user and code, per increasing timestamp. Then, we can just count the first row per group in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_code = code then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by code order by timestamp) as ranking
from (select t.*,
             lag(user_id) over (partition by code order by timestamp) as prev_code
      from t
     ) t;
```

The above will count a user id twice if it appears multiple times for a code (separated by other user ids).  If you want to count user ids based on their first appearance, then get the minimum timestamp and use that with `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by code order by min_timestamp) as ranking
from (select t.*,
             min(timestamp) over (partition by code, user) as min_timestamp
      from t
     ) t;
```